# mailbox library and repeated header fields

Tags: python, email, email-headers

Emails can contain multiple header line with the same header name (i.e., same key).  For example:

```
Received: from x ...
Received: from y ...
```

I'm using Python's [`mailbox`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mailbox.html) library.  What are the semantics of `mailbox`'s `keys()` and `items()` methods, if the email contains multiple header lines with the same name?

For the example above, will the returned list contained two entries for the two `Received` lines, or only one entry (since they have the same name)?  Are they guaranteed to be in the same order as they were found in the original email?

For comparison, the semantics of `__getitem__(h)` are explicitly documented: if there are multiple headers with name `h`, which one's value is returned is undefined.  Similarly, the semantics of `__setitem__()` and `__delitem__()` are fully defined.  However, the documentation for `keys()` and `items()` doesn't say what is or isn't guaranteed.